# Most fastest and efficient way to remove duplicates in Java

Tags: java, optimization, hashmap, time-complexity, hashset

I want to remove duplicated values in my data. I know it is frequently observed questions in stackoverflow but my problem is a little different because now I am handling very large size of data. Therefore I have to consider the execution time the most in my code.

As below snippet, I made a simple code for removing duplicated values.

```
// Suppose that the dataset is very huge so that
// multi-node resources should be necessary.    
String[] data = new String[10_000_000];

HashMap<String, String> uniqueItems = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (uniqueItems.containsKey(data[i])) {
        uniqueItems.remove(data[i]);
        uniqueItems.put(data[i], "inserted");
    } else {
        uniqueItems.put(data[i], "inserted");
    }
}
```

However, I don't like it because I think that other better data structures or different algorithms could efficiently remove duplicated than my code.

So I want to look for better ways to quickly remove duplicated values when the data is large.
I appreciate it if you could let me know the fastest way of removing duplicated values.

And also, I am wondering if the number of duplicated values could affect the performance. I mean if the duplicated values is 50% of the original data, then the selection of best algorithm and data structures will be changed? If so, I want to find a way that can achieve good performance in general cases.

Comment: Would you consider using a `Set` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717681/removing-duplicates-in-java-on-large-scale-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693408/java-optimize-hashset-for-large-scale-duplicate-detection for example. Or go for hadoop/map-reduce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065737/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-using-mapreduce ... so how much time again did you spent on doing your research?

Comment: Why do you remove and then re-insert the duplicate items?

Comment: For very large data sets perhaps a modified Merge-Sort which deletes all duplicates as soon as they are found might work well.

Comment: Replace the whole thing with `Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(data));`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your `uniqueItems` to a [`HashSet<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and your *for loop* to simply:

```
uniqueItems.add(data[i]);
```

If `add` returns `true` then you have inserted an unique string; `false` if duplicated.

Both algorithms should run in **O(n)** time in the best case, but using a `HashMap` when you don't care about the value (for a given key) is silly and wastes resources. A `HashSet` is a better fit for such cases.

You could also try a [`TreeSet<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to see what works best for your particular dataset. Probably will be worse, given JDK 8 new `HashSet` implementation: over crowded buckets are stored as mini tree sets automatically, providing a competitive performance even when the *hashing function* behaves badly. (This optimization is only possible for `Comparable` types such as `String`.)

---

**Brute force searching arrays**. In a simple, array based algorithm, where you search the entire array *before* inserting each element, you would get a very bad **O(n²)** performance.

As such, you might be tempted to *sort* your data first, placing duplicated elements *near* each other. This buys you a faster **O(n log n)** performance, but still behind the `HashMap/HashSet` version in the general case.

---

**Linear is theoretical best**. You can't detect *all* duplicates without visiting each  element at least *once*. As such, our current **O(n)** time complexity is really the best you can do here.

Of course, you can always try shaving down some of the hidden *constants* in the [Big O notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), but you won't arrive in a asymptotically better algorithm.

Comment: Is hashSet better than HashMap? I didn't get it

Comment: @sclee1 Both share the same hash table algorithm. But, if you really don't care about the stored value (for each key) then using a Hashmap is silly; you are better off using a Set instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. why your solution gives me O(n) if some condition are satisfied ?(because you say I need the luck)

Comment: @sclee1 It depends on how your data is stored inside the ultra fast hashmap. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4553642) for further considerations.

Comment: Why do you think that using a HashMap had O(n²)?

Comment: @tobias_k you are right mate! I somehow thought he was using a simple array based algorithm. Running low on coffee here... :)

Comment: HashSet is costly in terms of memory consumption. Could be OK for a small collection, but 100GB+ lists that could be prohibitive. Better sort the array using QuickSort or MergeSort in O(NlogN) time, then remove duplicate items in O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

In your example the data[i] values are used as 'key's in
HashMap uniqueItems.

A HaspMap will always have unique keys. An existing key
will be overwritten by a put() operation. You need no conatinsKey() if
you want to add a new element.

Why do you remove and insert an existing key ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was my mistake :D